# Use Spring annotation to inject dependency

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

In my project, i see a spring dependency inujection syntax like this in my integration layer:

```
applicationContext.getBean("beanName");
```

where applicationContext instance of ClasspathXMLApplicationContext and "`beanName`" is defined in the spring xml.
If I want to inject it with Annotation, which one should I use? `@Inject,@Autowired,@Resource.` Seems like I cna use any one of these and I cannot seem to be able to decide which one.
This is SPring integration layer , not MVC layer but i dont think that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Inject` and `@Autowired` do the same thing, it autowires by type.  `@Inject` is preferred because it is a java annotation and does not couple you to Spring

`@Resource` autowires by name.  This is useful when you have many beans of the same type.  You can also use `@Named` along with `@Inject` for the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`@Inject` is synonymous to `@Autowired`.
`@Autowired` moreover offers **optional injection** `@Autowired(reqired=false)` `@Inject` doesn't have this option.

`@Inject` and `@Resource` is standardized in [**JSR-299**](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/) so it should be preffered if possible.

in short, order in which mentioned annotations match dependency to be injected:

> `@Autowired` and `@Inject`
>
> 1. Matches by Type
> 2. Restricts by Qualifiers   (`@Qualifier` annotation)
> 3. Matches by Name
>
> `@Resource`
>
> 1. Matches by Name
> 2. Matches by Type
> 3. Restricts by Qualifiers (`@Qualifier`, ignored if match is found by name)

You can find more about these annotations here:
http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/

Answer (score 1):

@Inject and @Autowired are similar. The native Spring annotation is @Autowired, even Spring also support the Java @Inject annotation, that makes the same.

@Resource is Java annotation, Spring also support that annotation. It means JNDI resource.

See
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html